# Bean from list gets not updated in JSF

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I struggled for a whole week now and dont get it work. The user objects dont get updated...
Here is the important xhtml part:

```
<p:dataTable id="usersTable" var="user" value="#{userBean.allUsers}">  
<p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{userBean.onRowToggle}" update=":form_user_management:tabView_viewUsers:messages" />  
<f:facet name="header">  
    User
</f:facet>  

<p:rowExpansion>  
    <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="10" style="width:300px;"  
                 styleClass=" ui-widget-content grid">  

        <p:panel id="panel" header="Benutzer bearbeiten">

            <p:messages id="msgs"/>

            <h:panelGrid columns="3" >
                <h:outputLabel for="firstname" value="Firstname: *" />
                <p:inputText id="firstname" value="#{user.userFirstName}" required="true" label="Firstname">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="2" />
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="firstname" display="icon"/>

                <h:outputLabel for="surname" value="Surname: *" />
                <p:inputText id="surname" value="#{user.userLastName}" label="Surname" required="true">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="2" />
                    <p:ajax update="msgSurname" event="keyup" />
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="surname" id="msgSurname" display="icon"/>

                <p:commandLink id="changepw" value="Passwort ändern" onclick="dlg.show()" title="Passwort ändern">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{user}" target="#{userBean.currentUser}" />
                </p:commandLink>

                <p:commandButton ajax="true" id="btnUpdateUser" value="Update" update=":form_user_management @all" actionListener="#{userBean.updateUser(user)}"/>
                <p:commandButton ajax="true" id="btnDeleteUser" value="Delete" update=":form_user_management" actionListener="#{userBean.deleteUser(user)}"/>  

            </h:panelGrid> 
        </p:panel>  
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:rowExpansion>
```

When I click on "Save" the expanded Row disappears, but the new values are not shown and the Java Method "userBean.updateUser(user)" gets only the old values of user object.

The head of UserBean is:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {
```

SessionScoped is from the javax.enterprise.context

I also tried to use the old @ManagedBean things, but that didnt help either. I think the problem is located in the xhtml file and with the ajax stuff...
Oh, and I use  and the other template stuff.

Using Primefaces 3.4 and Glassfish 3+

Full UserBean: http://pastebin.com/yQCgiM4E
Full Xhtml: http://pastebin.com/19TWt3Dv (line 110 is the interesting thing)

Comment: There's a lot going on in that rowExpansion. Maybe even too much. You can start by slimming it down, adding `<p:messages autoUpdate="true"/>` to your view and changing `actionListener` to `action`

Comment: Can you show me the complete xhtml page and UserBean?

Comment: sure, I added them as links in the bottom of the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my mate solved the problem himself by adding
 `return action.getActionEvent()+"?faces-redirect=true";`

in the action attribute, like so`<h:commandButton action="page1?faces-redirect=true" value="Page1" />`

this solved the ajax-delay-shit